# Accessing cffi enums

Tags: python, python-cffi

Suppose I define an enum under cffi:

```
from cffi import FFI
ffi = FFI()
ffi.cdef('typedef enum {RANDOM, IMMEDIATE, SEARCH} strategy;')
```

Now this can be easily accessed when calling `cdef` again. But how would I then like to access this enum in python, without re-declaring it? Can't find any mentions in the docs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `ffi.dlopen`, and access the enum value by qualifying using the return value of the `ffi.dlopen`:

```
>>> from cffi import FFI
>>> ffi = FFI()
>>> ffi.cdef('typedef enum {RANDOM, IMMEDIATE, SEARCH} strategy;')
>>> c = ffi.dlopen('c')
>>> c.RANDOM
0
>>> c.IMMEDIATE
1
>>> c.SEARCH
2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have wrapped over a library you can use the same above as following :

```
import _wrappedlib

print _wrappedlib.lib.RANDOM
```

Answer (score 0):

Following @falsetru's answer, `ffi.dlopen('c')` doesn't work anymore for Windows 7 and Python 3.7, but I discovered today that we can use any library instead of `'c'` and it still works. The recommended one at https://bugs.python.org/issue23606 is to use `ucrtbase.dll`, so we can do:

```
>>> ffi.cdef('#define MAX_PATH 260')
>>> ffi.dlopen('kernel32.dll').MAX_PATH
260
```

Another more complicated way for enums is to use `self.typeof('strategy').relements['RANDOM']`, but this does not work for `#define`s, so the above way is better.