# Fetching a C variable value in an enum using its name (a Python string) in Python

Tags: python, c, variables, enums, python-cffi

Basically, I am wrapping a C API in Python (using CFFI (which is awesome)).

I have an enum in that C API:

```
typedef enum
{
    enum1 = value1;
    enum2 = value2;
    ...
} enumSomething;
```

In Python, I receive the name of a variable which is in that enumeration, as a string : `"enum1"`. I would like to get `value1`.

Using `CFFI`, you can wrap an enum and access its members easily ([here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27223489/accessing-cffi-enums)). My problem here is that I have strings that represent the name of the variable, not the variable itself.

Thus, `cwrapper.c."enum1"` would not work (`cwrapper` being the name of the module that wraps and `c` the name returned by `ffi.dlopen(libname)` while wrapping the library).

I could make a dictionary that would map the variable name as a string to the real variable, such as:

```
enum = { "enum1" : cwrapper.c.enum1, "enum2" : cwrapper.c.enum2, ... }
```

But at this point, I would better rewrite the enum as a Python dictionary.

I know I could also use a regex to read the C file, but I think there is still a better way for handling that, that I haven't thought of. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cwrapper.c."enum1"` is not valid syntax in Python in general. You need to use `getattr`:

```
>>> getattr(cwrapper.c, "enum1")
42
```

However a cleaner approach is to get the actual type using `typeof`; then get its `relements`, which is a dictionary!

```
>>> import cffi
>>> ffi = cffi.FFI()
>>> ffi.cdef('typedef enum {RANDOM, IMMEDIATE, SEARCH} strategy;')
>>> typeof_strategy = ffi.typeof('strategy')
>>> typeof_strategy.relements
{'RANDOM': 0, 'SEARCH': 2, 'IMMEDIATE': 1}
>>> typeof_strategy.relements['SEARCH']
2
```

Comment: I actually wanted to point out that it would not be valid syntax. However, I did not know about getattr. Thanks, it works!

Comment: Why would it be cleaner to use that way rather than just getattr?

Comment: because `getattr` can retrieve not just the enum values, but anything that way including `printf`, or anything that was just included in those `cdef`s.

Comment: With the latter you can make sure you're ever only resolving appropriate values

Answer (score 2):

Building on Antti's answer, a proper Python `Enum` could be built:

```
Strategy = enum.Enum('Strategy', ffi.typeof('strategy').relements)

list(Strategy)
# [<Strategy.RANDOM: 0>, <Strategy.IMMEDIATE: 1>, <Strategy.SEARCH: 2>]
```