# import a full c enum using cython automatically

Tags: python, c, enums, cython

im using cython to import c enums from .h file to my python code (the goal is to have one place that will include the enums for both of my programs).
so i have my `enums.h` file:

```c
typedef enum Numbers{
    ONE=1, TWO, THREE
} Numbers;
```

and i have my enums.pyx

```py
cdef extern from "enums.h":
    cpdef enum Numbers:
        ONE,
        TWO,
        THREE
```

and this code works in the sense that it imports the enum to be accessible from the python code with the right values.
i want to take it a step further and want to automatically identify the members of the c enums,
so the pyx file would update automaticly, when i do:

```py
cdef extern from "enums.h":
    cpdef enum Numbers:
        pass
```

i get a Numbers enum in the python but without members (so even if I do `Numbers(1)` ill get an error).

is there a way to identify the c enum members automatically?

Comment: If with plenty of time, could try [swig](http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html). Cython is a powerful but low level tool, while swig can do something automatically.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66037988/208880) shows how to automatically create a Python `Enum` from a `.h` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cython does not have any ability to scan C files and generate declarations so the direct answer to your question is "no" and is very likely to remain "no".

Other tools do have greater introspection ability. CFFI [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27223489/accessing-cffi-enums). I'm sure there are others.

You could obviously write a short script using one of these tools to try to generate (parts of) your automatically Cython files, but it's definitely outside the scope of Cython on its own.